# How to make the circle smaller(tikz mindmap)

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

I'm drawing a mind map, but I don't know how the root node becomes smaller. I think the following code should be able to achieve the required functions, but the result fails. How can I improve the code?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\begin{document}

\tikz
[root concept/.append style={concept color=blue!30,minimum size=3.5cm},mindmap]
\node [concept] {Root concept};


\tikz
[root concept/.append style={concept color=blue!30,minimum size=0.1cm},mindmap,inner sep=0cm]
\node [concept] {R};

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use a negative value for inner sep for example `inner sep=-1cm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `root concept` style used by option `mindmap` is defined by

```
\tikzset{
  root concept/.style={
    minimum size=4cm,text width=3.5cm,font=\pgfutil@font@large
  }
}
```

See related source lines [here](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/9ac32f11fd2f8255a8a74b0994cb9aed5c42a3e7/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarymindmap.code.tex#L274-L289). Hence you need to adjust `text width` as well.

In the following example, `text width=` is appended to the second `\tikz`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\begin{document}

\tikz
[root concept/.append style={concept color=blue!30,minimum size=3.5cm},mindmap]
\node [concept] {Root concept};


\tikz
[root concept/.append style={concept color=blue!30,minimum size=0.1cm, text width=},mindmap]
\node [concept] {R};

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this explanation is very clear and clear, and it's great! !